# VNC connection refused

Tags: pi-4, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running the default OS and VNC has been turned on and working for many weeks now. Suddenly today I tried to connect to the RPi using the VNC client on my iPhone and an error occurred. The error message shown is `An authentication error occurred. See the VNC Server error log for details.` I ran the following commands and got these results:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep vnc | tail

[...]
Apr 28 22:06:37 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[623,root]: Connections: connected: 192.168.0.204::60769 (TCP)
Apr 28 22:06:46 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[623,root]: SAuthUserPasswd: Auth error: /: permissions are not restrictive enough
Apr 28 22:06:46 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[623,root]: Connections: disconnected: 192.168.0.204::60769 (TCP) ([AuthError] An authentication error occurred.  See the VNC Server error log for details.)

sudo cat /var/log/vncserver-x11.log

[...]
<13> 2022-04-30T18:50:18.417Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: Connections: connected: 192.168.0.204::61654 (TCP)
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:18.421Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SConnection: Client needs protocol version 5.0
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:18.421Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SProtoV5Up: Choosing cipher suite RA4_128 [0x0202] (algorithms: RSA-OAEP, ECDHE-Curve25519, SHA-256, AES-GCM-128)
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:18.507Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SAuthProtoImpl: Offering auth method UserPasswd(1) [required=1]
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:18.512Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SAuthProtoImpl: Client chose auth method UserPasswd(1)
<11> 2022-04-30T18:50:27.658Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SAuthUserPasswd: Auth error: /: permissions are not restrictive enough
<13> 2022-04-30T18:50:27.658Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: Connections: disconnected: 192.168.0.204::61654 (TCP) ([AuthError] An authentication error occurred.  See the VNC Server error log for details.)
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:27.659Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SMsgWriter: framebuffer updates 0
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:27.659Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SMsgWriter:   CopyRect rects 0, bytes 0, pixels 0
<14> 2022-04-30T18:50:27.659Z raspberrypi vncserver-x11[613]: SMsgWriter:   raw bytes equivalent 0, compression ratio nan
```

(these lines appear every time I try to connect)

I really don't understand why this stopped working all of a sudden. Although I have services like docker and home assistant running continuously, I did not install or change anything myself in between VNC working and not working.

I have searched for this error to understand what it means and how to solve this but have really found nothing related to VNC or even just this error message in general.

Comment: "See the VNC Server error log for details" - so what's in there? /var/log/vncserver-x11.log

Comment: @Dougie edited the question. What appears is basically the same, and the error is exactly the same.

Comment: You're going to have to ask the RealVNC folks at https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/community/topics 

Or try a fresh copy of RaspiOS Bullseye 22-04-22 and see if that gets the same failure.

Comment: @Dougie Currently it's not possible for me to try a fresh install, but as another person wrote in an answer that has since been deleted, this exact error was also happening for them with a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Auth error: /: permissions are not restrictive enough
```

Ensure that the / folder is owned by root and its permission mode is set to 755:

```
chown root.root /
chmod 755 /
```

You may also need to check these permissions for /usr folder

```
chown root.root /usr
chmod 755 /usr
```